# ckeditor virtual keyboard issue for mutiple keystroke

Tags: keyboard, virtual

there is issue on ckeditor virtual keyboard after opening and pressing ok or cancel many time .While typing from keyboard it is press many time depending on open and close of virtual keyboard and if we use virtual keyboard it is perfect.

Comment: not getting what exactly you are saying.. please explain it in more detail

Comment: i have integrated virtual keyboard plugin in ckeditor when i open virtual keyboard and if i close or save doing this activity many time while pressing key from pc keyboard it typed many time.

Comment: I guess when you are closing your keboard it may hide but not getting closed so when you press any word it will add it to editor many times